# System.Net.Sockets in WP8

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8

Got unknown issue with System.Net.Sockets in WP8.
The communication built on next schema - 4 first bytes - for package length, next 4 bytes for package number, and data. So [4][4][{any}] is a TCP package.
Reading of incoming data goes by next steps.
1. Read first 8 bytes.
2. Get package length from the first 4 bytes to determine size of incoming data.
3. Resize buffer to a proper size.
4. Read incoming data in buffer with offset 8 bytes.
I am sending a lot of packages to server.
Sometimes server's responses in incoming buffer are valid and can be read one by one.

But sometimes it seems the first 8 bytes from incoming data are skipped and with the steps 1-4 I am reading the first 8 bytes from the package's data.

Infinite loop for receiving

```
while (_channel.Opened)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Wait for incoming... ");
    Stream responseStream = await _channel.Receive();
    HandleIncomingData(responseStream);
}
```

Here code for socket:

```
    public async Task<Stream> Receive()
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[8];
        ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        args.SetBuffer(buff, 0, buff.Length);

        EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs> completed = (sender, eventArgs) => mre.Set();

        EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs> removeSubscription = (sender, eventArgs) => args.Completed -= completed;

        args.Completed += completed;
        args.Completed += removeSubscription;

        _connectionSocket.ReceiveAsync(args);
        mre.Wait();

        args.Completed -= removeSubscription;

        int len = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0);
        int num = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 4);

        if (Math.Abs(_packageNumber - num) < 3)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref buff, len);
            args.SetBuffer(buff, 8, buff.Length - 8);

            args.Completed += completed;
            args.Completed += removeSubscription;
            mre.Reset();
            _connectionSocket.ReceiveAsync(args);
            mre.Wait();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Recv TCP package: {0}", args.Buffer.ToDebugString());
        if (args.BytesTransferred == 0)
            throw new SocketException();

        byte[] result = new byte[buff.Length - 8];
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(buff, 8, result, 0, result.Length);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(result, false);
        return await Task.FromResult(stream);
    }
```

Comment: The sender and receiver should use the same content protocol. Is there any?

Comment: Package structure is same for all directions. In package's data could be everything. But package's length must be correct

Comment: Usually, such problems are a result of implementing the recv loop and handling buffer indexes/pointers incorrectly. Code pls:)

Comment: You're aware that a read operation may not give you exactly what you're after ? Ie first read may give less than 8 bytes or exactly 8 bytes (can't be more due to your buffer size). Then when you read the message, you know you won't get more, but it may take more than one read to get the data for the one message.

Comment: yes. First read may give less than 8 bytes if there are less than 8 bytes. If response came - there are more than 8 bytes. read operation made as blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 100% issue with crossthreading. Did the same in Console app. 
If here

```
mre.Reset();
_connectionSocket.ReceiveAsync(args);
mre.Wait();
```

before mre.Wait() put Thread.Sleep(n), where n > 1 - everything works fine.
But this is very rude solution